# Simple and political question

Tags: riddle, english

I'm a man who rule my country,

I'm the only rule my country,

While others are my troops, my commanders, and my commoners,

My system was "one-person".

What am i?

Comment: Um... the person who caused WWII?

Comment: Welcome to puzzling by the way! Just so you know, on this site, when grammar is incorrect we tend to assume that it means something more than it otherwise would. If what you wrote is intentional, that's fine, otherwise, please look into correcting it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a straight dictionary definition request and does not read like a riddle at all.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> The pope

I'm a man who rule my country,

> The vatican city is ruled by the pope

I'm the only rule my country,

> The pope (non-specifically) is the only ruler the vatican city has had

While others are my troops, my commanders, and my commoners,

> It contains priests, cardinals, and subjects (each of those are their counterparts in catholicism)

My system was "one-person".

> It's an absolute monarchy, and it's religion is monotheistic, more specifically Jesus (one person).

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> A Monarch or Dictator?

Explanation:

> Both can be single male leaders with absolute authority/control in "governing" their country.

Comment: Probably the first one: the [tag:english] tag might point to the etymology of that word, which fits the fourth clue quite nicely.

Answer (score -1):

The *Simple* answer:

> An autocrat, dictator, despot, or tyrant.

Comment: Welcome Puzzling.SE!  Please hide your answer with ">!" at the front of the answer.